# Embedded Jetty (Access) Request Logging

Tags: jetty, jersey-2.0

I am working on creating some rest API using JAX-RS and embedded Jetty.I Enable Server logging by adding LogRequestHandler in Server.java file.

Question is why jetty is writing 200 for every request `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 -  -  [03/Nov/2016:16:59:57 +0500] "GET /app/check HTTP/1.1" 200 -  4`

though check end point is not implemented not exists in the app.

source code:

```java
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    //context.setContextPath("/");

    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
    config.packages("server");
    ServletHolder servlet = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(config));
    context.addServlet(servlet,"/*");

    NCSARequestLog requestLog = new NCSARequestLog("/var/logs/jetty/log-yyyy_mm_dd.request.log");
    requestLog.setAppend(true);
    requestLog.setExtended(false);
    requestLog.setLogTimeZone("GMT+5");
    requestLog.setLogLatency(true);
    requestLog.setRetainDays(90);
    RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
    requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(requestLog);

    HandlerList topLevelHandlers = new HandlerList();
    topLevelHandlers.addHandler(context);
    topLevelHandlers.addHandler(requestLogHandler);

    try {
        jettyServer.setHandler(topLevelHandlers);
        jettyServer.dumpStdErr();
        jettyServer.start();
    }
```

Comment: Post how you are adding the RequestHandler to your app.  Its location in the handler tree is important.

Comment: RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
        requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(requestLog);      ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.addServlet(servlet, "/*");   server.addHandler()

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code, makes it easier to read/search.

Comment: edited. Please note that it logs 200 for every request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix this by re-arranging the handler in the following order

I set resource handler as handlers for the request log (ie it is the outer handler) then the requestlog handler is added to the main jetty handlers. Then requests would go to request log -> handlers -> request log and back to jetty

Answer (score 5):

**Updated Answer**

Do not use `RequestLogHandler` it is now deprecated.

Any `RequestLog` interface implementation should be set on the `Server.setRequestLog(RequestLog)` method now.

This will catch more requests, even 400 (Bad Request), requests that fail parsing, requests that don't belong to a context, and even requests that are not dispatched to the handler tree.

**Original Answer**

The `RequestLogHandler` should be executed before any context its tracking.

The ideal way to use `RequestLog` is to set it on the server and *not use* the `RequestLogHandler` ...

```java
jettyServer.setRequestLog(requestLog);
```

But if you have a need to use it as a Handler, then you should make sure it executes before any contexts you want to track ...

```java
HandlerList topLevelHandlers = new HandlerList();
topLevelHandlers.addHandler(requestLogHandler);
topLevelHandlers.addHandler(context);
jettyServer.setHandler(topLevelHandlers);
```

or wrap the context with the request log handler ...

```java
requestLogHandler.setHandler(context);
jettyServer.setHandler(requestLogHandler);
```